# How to make an object's texture conjoin when exported to Photoshop?

Tags: rendering, texturing, export

I have an object that I have created in Blender out of a bunch of cubes. When I export it .3ds into Photoshop, the cubes are each individually texturized, but I want them to all blend together as if they were all one object. I can't for the life of me figure this out.

[image: Example]

You can clearly see each individual cube, but I want them to all blend together as one object. How do I do this?

Thanks,
Eedis

Comment: Do you want to physically join the cubes? or just make it look like they are a single object?

Comment: I know how to physically join the cubes, CTRL+J, but it didn't make them look physically joined after the export. So I guess the latter of what you asked; 'make it look like they are a single object'.

Comment: When you make the a single object with Ctrl+J, they are still separate. You can merge them together by removing the duplicate vertices, with `Tab` to enter edit mode `A` to select all `W` *> Remove doubles* to remove the duplicate verts. Note that you may need to tweak the the *merge distance* in the redo menu.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :) If you answer the question, I can register and then vote your answer for the rep. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To physically merge the cubes into one solid mesh:

1. Join the cubes into on object by selecting them all and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
2. Switch into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), and remove doubles (<kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove doubles*)
3. You may need to remove internal faces too. Select internal faces by pressing *Internal faces* in *3D view > Header > Select*, then delete them with <kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Faces*.